# Translate text into device language in Android

Tags: android, locale

I want to translate my text into device language.

So I tried below code

```
    String InputString="My text";
    String OutputString = null;
    
    Language fromLanguage = Language.ENGLISH;
    Language toLanguage = Language.valueOf(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage().toUpperCase());
    
    try {
        
        Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://android-er.blogspot.com/");
        OutputString = Translate.execute(InputString, 
                fromLanguage, toLanguage);
    
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        OutputString = InputString;
    }
    
    return OutputString;
```

If device language is English it executes well but i changed to any other language then it shows

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FRANÇAIS is not a constant in the enum type class com.google.api.translate.Language
```

not `FRANCAIS` if I select any language except English it shows `IllegalArgumentException` with selected language.

What have I done wrong, or is there another way to translate text into device language?

Comment: You cannot translate Language directly.But if you store the string values in res/values-fr and setlangauge to french in native locale settings it automatically takes the string values in values-fr.

Comment: For completing the advice above from @Sando, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328331/9160102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this document, it explains all you need to know: [Android Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)