# How to fix Translation not working with TextView.setText()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm localizing my application and currently facing a problem. I have a textview which shows when the application was last updated abd I have a string resource "Last Updated: " for that. I used

```
lastUpdate.setText(R.string.last_updated + dateString);
```

My code works perfect in English language but in case of other languages the Textview acts strange and shows numbers in place of the text.

For example: When I set the language to Hindi the text **Last Updated** gets changed to 2131689604. How can this issue be overcome?

Comment: check what `R.string.last_updated` is. You will be surprised, it is not a `String`. It is the String resource ID, which is `int`. You can't mix resource ID + dateString

Comment: You'll need `getResources().getString(R.string.last_updated)` instead of just the id.

Comment: Whoops! Seems I completely forgot that

Comment: @JoyDey if you find the solution please mark the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get string by using this

```
 lastUpdate.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.last_updated) + dateString);
```